scrape path of Institutions in gerit.org
I would like to scrape the hierarchy of institutions of German universities. The attached script successfully scrapes the div-classes of the individual institutions, but unfortunately I am not able to recreate the paths realistically in the data preparation. My question is whether anyone has an idea of how to create the paths correctly during the scraping process.
What I would need is a path variable that looks like this, for example:
https://www.gerit.org/de/institutiondetail/10282
Fakultät 1: Wirtschafts- und Sozialwissenschaftliche Fakultät >Fakultätsbereich Soziologie und Sozialpsychologie > Institut für Soziologie und Sozialpsychologie (ISS) > Lehrstuhl für Wirtschafts- und Sozialpsychologie > Professur Hölzl
Here is my script so far:
#////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
# Scrape Gerit
#//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 

# loading needed libraries -----------------------------------------------------
if (!require("pacman")) install.packages("pacman")
pacman::p_load(tidyverse, rvest, xml2, readr,RSelenium,openxlsx)

#////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
# START RSELENIUM
#//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 

# Starten einer Remote-Sitzung mit Chrome
driver <- rsDriver(browser = "chrome", chromever = "125.0.6422.60", port = 4112L)

# Zugriff auf die gestartete Sitzung
rmdr <- driver[["client"]]


    
scrape_gerit <- function(url, uni_name) {
  
  # Versuche, die Seite abzurufen, und behandle den Fehler
  page <- tryCatch({
    read_html(url)
  }, error = function(e) {
    warning(paste("Fehler beim Abrufen der Seite:", url))
    return(NA)
  })
  
  # Überprüfe, ob die Seite erfolgreich abgerufen wurde
  if (is.na(page)) {
    # Rückgabe eines Datenrahmens mit NA-Werten
    return(tibble(Einrichtung = NA, Level_0 = NA, Einrichtung_url = NA, Einrichtung_Fach = NA, HS = uni_name))
  } else {
    # Füge den restlichen Code hier ein, um die Seite zu verarbeiten
    rmdr$navigate(url)
    
    rmdr$findElement("xpath", '//*[(@id = "associatedData")]//a[(((count(preceding-sibling::*) + 1) = 1) and parent::*)]//span')$clickElement()
    
    # Inhalte der aktuellen Seite extrahieren und direkt verarbeiten
    Einrichtung <- rmdr$getPageSource()[[1]] %>% 
      read_html() %>% 
      html_nodes(".associated-institution") %>% 
      html_text()
    
    Einrichtung_url <- rmdr$getPageSource()[[1]] %>% 
      read_html() %>% 
      html_nodes(" #associated a")  |>
      html_attr("href")
    
    Level_0 <- rmdr$getPageSource()[[1]] %>% 
      read_html() %>% 
      html_nodes(".associated-contend") %>%
      map_chr(~ {
        node <- .x
        class_attr <- html_attr(node, "class")
        if (str_detect(class_attr, "level0")) {
          html_text(node)
        } else {
          NA
        }
      })

    Level_1  <- rmdr$getPageSource()[[1]] %>% 
      read_html() %>% 
      html_nodes(".associated-contend") %>%
      map_chr(~ {
        node <- .x
        class_attr <- html_attr(node, "class")
        if (str_detect(class_attr, "level1")) {
          html_text(node)
        } else {
          NA
        }
      })

    Level_2  <- rmdr$getPageSource()[[1]] %>% 
      read_html() %>% 
      html_nodes(".associated-contend") %>%
      map_chr(~ {
        node <- .x
        class_attr <- html_attr(node, "class")
        if (str_detect(class_attr, "level2")) {
          html_text(node)
        } else {
          NA
        }
      })

    Level_3  <- rmdr$getPageSource()[[1]] %>% 
      read_html() %>% 
      html_nodes(".associated-contend") %>%
      map_chr(~ {
        node <- .x
        class_attr <- html_attr(node, "class")
        if (str_detect(class_attr, "level3")) {
          html_text(node)
        } else {
          NA
        }
      })

    Level_4  <- rmdr$getPageSource()[[1]] %>% 
      read_html() %>% 
      html_nodes(".associated-contend") %>%
      map_chr(~ {
        node <- .x
        class_attr <- html_attr(node, "class")
        if (str_detect(class_attr, "level4")) {
          html_text(node)
        } else {
          NA
        }
      })

    Level_5  <- rmdr$getPageSource()[[1]] %>% 
      read_html() %>% 
      html_nodes(".associated-contend") %>%
      map_chr(~ {
        node <- .x
        class_attr <- html_attr(node, "class")
        if (str_detect(class_attr, "level5")) {
          html_text(node)
        } else {
          NA
        }
      })

    Level_6  <- rmdr$getPageSource()[[1]] %>% 
      read_html() %>% 
      html_nodes(".associated-contend") %>%
      map_chr(~ {
        node <- .x
        class_attr <- html_attr(node, "class")
        if (str_detect(class_attr, "level6")) {
          html_text(node)
        } else {
          NA
        }
      })

    noMoreSubs <- rmdr$getPageSource()[[1]] %>% 
      read_html() %>% 
      html_nodes(".associated-contend") %>%
      map_chr(~ {
        node <- .x
        class_attr <- html_attr(node, "class")
        if (str_detect(class_attr, "noMoreSubs")) {
          html_text(node)
        } else {
          NA
        }
    })
    
    Einrichtung_url <- paste0("https://gerit.org", Einrichtung_url)
    
    # Funktion zum Extrahieren der Daten von Gerit
    extract_data <- function(url) {
      message("Starte scraping von: ", url)
      page <- tryCatch({
        read_html(url)
      }, error = function(e) {
        warning(paste("Fehler beim Abrufen der Seite:", url))
        return(NA)
      })
      
      if (is.na(page)) {
        return(NA)
      } else {
        data <- page %>%
          html_nodes(".institutionFach") %>%
          html_text()
        message("Scraping beendet")
        return(data)
      }
    }
    
    # Anwenden der Funktion auf jede URL aus Gerit
    results <- lapply(Einrichtung_url, extract_data)
    
    # Füge Daten zusammen
    uni_name <- tibble(Einrichtung = Einrichtung, 
                       Level_0 = Level_0,
                       Level_1 = Level_1,
                       Level_2 = Level_2,
                       Level_3 = Level_3,
                       Level_4 = Level_4,
                       Level_5 = Level_5,
                       Level_6 = Level_6,
                       noMoreSubs = noMoreSubs,
                       Einrichtung_url = Einrichtung_url, 
                       Einrichtung_Fach = results,
                       HS = uni_name)
    
    return(uni_name)
  }
}


gerit_unis <- data.frame(
  Hochschule = c("Universität zu Köln", "Technische Universität München", "Rheinisch-Westfälische Technische Hochschule Aachen"),
  Gerit_Url = c("https://gerit.org/de/institutiondetail/10282", "https://gerit.org/de/institutiondetail/10125", "https://gerit.org/de/institutiondetail/10293")
)

# Funktion zum Scrapen über jede URL in hochschulen
ergebnisse <- lapply(1:nrow(gerit_unis), function(i) {
  res <- scrape_gerit(url = gerit_unis$Gerit_Url[i], uni_name = gerit_unis$Hochschule[i])
  res$HS <- gerit_unis$Hochschule[i]
  return(res)
})

save(ergebnisse, file = "Data/ergebnisse_ext.rda")
 
driver[["server"]]$stop()



I've not been through your example in detail, but in rvest you can use html_attr(name = "href") to get the URL target of an <a ... > html element. You might be able to just replace your html_text() with this, depending on the structure of those nodes.

You are more likely to receive an answer if you reduce your question to the smallest code chunk possible to replicate your problem.

Too bad the question was closed, even though @margusl understood what you were asking! Here is a bit of different solution, emphasizing that you are asking a question about a 'graph' and so graph-based algorithms (i.e., shortest path between two nodes) is appropriate.

@MartinMorgan , impressive!  Thank you so much for all your work with rjsoncons

That whole tree structure is embedded in one of the <script> elements in the page source, so as an alternative to RSelenium you can also extract it with just rvest and parse with jsonlite. From there it takes some wrangiling to properly flatten that tree.
Functions for each process step:
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

# extract part of js script, __PRELOADED_STATE__ 
# returns list(json_str = "...", root = "Institute name")
get_prel_state_json <- function(url_){
  html <- read_html(url_)
  root <- 
    html_element(html, '#associated-root-link') |>
    html_text(trim = TRUE)
  
  html |>
    html_element(xpath = '//script[contains(text(),"window.__PRELOADED_STATE__")]') |>
    html_text() |>
    str_remove(fixed("window.__PRELOADED_STATE__ = ")) |>
    list(json_str = _, root = root)
}

# parse __PRELOADED_STATE__, return institution tree as deeply nested list
get_institution_tree <- function(prel_state_json){
  jsonlite::fromJSON(prel_state_json, simplifyVector = FALSE)[["institutionDetail"]][["institution"]][["tree"]][["children"]]
}

# unnest one level in nested tibble
unnest_children <- function(df_, level_name){
  df_ |>
    hoist(children, 
          "{level_name}.id" := "id", 
          "{level_name}.de" := list("name", "de"), 
          children_ = "children") |>
    select(-children) |>
    rename(children = children_) |>
    unnest_longer(children, keep_empty = TRUE)
}

# create flat data frame from tree
rectangle_tree <- function(children_list){
  # get number of institution levels from tree depth
  inst_levels <- (pluck_depth(children_list) %/% 2) - 1
  # iteratively call unnest_children() for the number of institute levels on 
  # tibble(children = children_list)
  reduce(str_c("l", 1:inst_levels), unnest_children, .init = tibble(children = children_list)) |>
    # remove last (hopefully only NA filled) children column
    select(-children)
  
}  

# select columns from 1 to level.name (ex: "l3.de")
# construct urls from rightmost id values (ex: l3.id ) and 
# paths from all selected level names
level_url_paths <- function(df_, level_name){  
  df_ |>
    select(1:any_of(level_name)) |>
    # if inclusion of next level introduced NAs, we are not interested
    # of this record as it was already included in previous level
    drop_na() |>
    distinct() |>
    rowwise() |>
    mutate(url  = c_across(ends_with("id")) |> na.omit() |> last() %>% str_c("https://www.gerit.org/de/institutiondetail/",.),
           path = c_across(ends_with("de")) |> na.omit() |> str_c(collapse = " > ")) |>
    ungroup() |>
    select(url, path)
}

get_url_paths <- function(df_){
  # from    "l1.id" "l1.de" "l2.id" "l2.de" "l3.id" "l3.de" "l4.id" "l4.de"
  # extract "l1.de" "l2.de" "l3.de" "l4.de"
  names(df_)[c(FALSE, TRUE)] |>
    map(level_url_paths, df_ = df_) |>
    list_rbind()
}

Main loop:
gerit_unis <- tibble(
  Gerit_Url = c(
    "https://gerit.org/de/institutiondetail/10282",
    "https://gerit.org/de/institutiondetail/10125",
    "https://gerit.org/de/institutiondetail/10293"
  )
)

url_paths <- 
  gerit_unis$Gerit_Url |>
  # get_prel_state_json return named list(json_str, root)
  map(get_prel_state_json) %>% 
  # use root node names as list name
  set_names(map_chr(., "root")) |>
  # keep only json string from list(json_str, root)
  map("json_str") |>
  map(get_institution_tree) |>
  map(rectangle_tree) |> 
  map(get_url_paths) |>
  list_rbind(names_to = "inst")


head(url_paths)
#> # A tibble: 6 × 3
#>   inst                url                                              path     
#>   <chr>               <chr>                                            <chr>    
#> 1 Universität zu Köln https://www.gerit.org/de/institutiondetail/14036 Fakultät…
#> 2 Universität zu Köln https://www.gerit.org/de/institutiondetail/14035 Fakultät…
#> 3 Universität zu Köln https://www.gerit.org/de/institutiondetail/27006 Fakultät…
#> 4 Universität zu Köln https://www.gerit.org/de/institutiondetail/14034 Fakultät…
#> 5 Universität zu Köln https://www.gerit.org/de/institutiondetail/14032 Fakultät…
#> 6 Universität zu Köln https://www.gerit.org/de/institutiondetail/14030 Fakultät…
tail(url_paths)
#> # A tibble: 6 × 3
#>   inst                                                url                  path 
#>   <chr>                                               <chr>                <chr>
#> 1 Rheinisch-Westfälische Technische Hochschule Aachen https://www.gerit.o… Faku…
#> 2 Rheinisch-Westfälische Technische Hochschule Aachen https://www.gerit.o… Faku…
#> 3 Rheinisch-Westfälische Technische Hochschule Aachen https://www.gerit.o… Faku…
#> 4 Rheinisch-Westfälische Technische Hochschule Aachen https://www.gerit.o… Faku…
#> 5 Rheinisch-Westfälische Technische Hochschule Aachen https://www.gerit.o… Faku…
#> 6 Rheinisch-Westfälische Technische Hochschule Aachen https://www.gerit.o… Faku…

Test with "Professur Hölzl" and "Fakultät 1: Wirtschafts- und Sozialwissenschaftliche Fakultät" :
url_paths |>
  filter(str_detect(path, "Professur Hölzl") | path == "Fakultät 1: Wirtschafts- und Sozialwissenschaftliche Fakultät") |>
  # just to print long(ish) string values
  jsonlite::toJSON(pretty = TRUE)
#> [
#>   {
#>     "inst": "Universität zu Köln",
#>     "url": "https://www.gerit.org/de/institutiondetail/14036",
#>     "path": "Fakultät 1: Wirtschafts- und Sozialwissenschaftliche Fakultät"
#>   },
#>   {
#>     "inst": "Universität zu Köln",
#>     "url": "https://www.gerit.org/de/institutiondetail/309061914",
#>     "path": "Fakultät 1: Wirtschafts- und Sozialwissenschaftliche Fakultät > Fakultätsbereich Soziologie und Sozialpsychologie > Institut für Soziologie und Sozialpsychologie (ISS) > Lehrstuhl für Wirtschafts- und Sozialpsychologie > Professur Hölzl"
#>   }
#> ]

Created on 2024-06-07 with reprex v2.1.0

Thank you!
I modified the code slightly and applied it to 30 universities.
I noticed that the paths of the div-class level1 institutions are not scraped. Unfortunately I can't find out why.
Here is a working example:
https://gist.github.com/maltehueckstaedt/a97bb5b503328209c9dd13ecba46f229

Ah, I just notice that it's not just level 1 institutions but all possible levels that are affected.

@Cheroff_Faces , indeed -- that approach only worked for end nodes, thos without any children. I updated url & path creation, not the most efficient way for sure, but should do the trick. It selects columns up to desired level so all institutions should be included in the final url & path list.

great, thank you! unfortunately I can't apply your solution to the other URLs. The unnest_children function keeps returning this error, which I can't quite fix:
Error in hoist():
! .data[[.col]] must be a list, not a logical vector.
Run rlang::last_trace() to see where the error occurred.
Is there perhaps a solution that is equally applicable to all 30 urls as here: https://gist.github.com/maltehueckstaedt/a97bb5b503328209c9dd13ecba46f229

@Cheroff_Faces ,  apparently tree depth varies. If there are only 5 levels, hoist tries to access children column that holds no values. I refactored it a bit and number of levels is not hardcoded anymore.

thank you very much, that's the solution! it saved me a lot of time and helped a lot!!!
